# Practical use of VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT alone

Tags: graphics, rendering, vulkan

Is there any practical use of `VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT` / `VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_READ_NONCOHERENT_BIT_EXT` alone? Basically, these access bits exist for blending and logic operations, thus they make sense only in conjunction with `VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_LOAD` uses only `VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT`.

Comment: Ahh, didn't know that. And is there any practical reason why you would load a color attachment without writing to it?

Comment: Ok, preserve attachments, I guess.

Comment: @plasmacel It is irrelevant if you write to the color attachment or not. The load itself is always read-only.